# Homebrew in bash profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

I'm having an issue with my bash profile on my mac.  Given the following from my .bash_profile

```
FOO="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin"
BAR="$(brew --prefix ruby)/bin"
BAZ="$(brew --prefix python)/bin"
```

The first line successfully completes, but the two following lines print the following error when I start terminal

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

When I run `brew --prefix ruby` or `brew --prefix python` at the command line after terminal starts, it prints out their respective paths.

Can anybody figure this out?

Comment: Are they the exact commands you have and no others? It looks like you edited it especially as the bins suggest you are changing your PATH and it is those lines we need to see? To debug put a `echo $PATH` before each line

Comment: The lines starting with BAR and BAZ in your .bash_profile file are probably poorly formatted. Check this with a decent text editor (e.g TextWrangler)

Answer (score 3):

The `brew` command is in `/usr/local/bin`, so you need to ensure that you either use the full path to `brew` in your commands, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/brew` or you need to set your `PATH` environment variable in your profile *before* using `brew`, e.g.:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: As this is part of the standard default I would suggest this is a comment asking for more details

Comment: @Mark Sorry - what is part of the standard default of what? How can this be a comment - it is clearly an answer offering the OP 2 possible solutions. And why would I ask for more details - I can clearly see what the problem is and what the answer is.

Comment: In that case why does the first line work?

Comment: @Mark Let's continue this discussion when the OP tells us whether my *"comment"* solves his problem, and you answer my question above.